# Git Merge Branch

Tags: git, merge, branch

I'm experiencing a problem in git branch merging(a whole branch merging instead of picking), And I found an old file is kept even if the file was modified after several versions in another branch. No matter what merge direction I choose. Branch A->B or Branch B->A, it's always like this. I'm frustrated since it might lose some of my changes if I do not do individual file check.
Could any one let me know what's going on, what's the merge mechanism or what I should do to make things right. Great thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "an old file is kept"? Are there two versions of the file (old version in branch A and newer version in branch B) and git always automatically merges it so you only get to keep the old version?

Comment: The act of making a merge, in Git, means to find a *merge base* (some specific commit, which is in the history of both of the two commits being merged) and take all the changes made *from* that base, *to* both tips.  Think of it as "Alice started with 13 items and added 2 to get 15 items, and Bob starts with the same 13 and added 1 item to get 14 items; so we will start with that same 13 now, and add all 3 to get 16 items."  It doesn't matter which way you do this (Alice's into Bob's, or Bob's into Alice's): you get all 16 items either way.

Comment: Are you sure the merge was successful? Or are you in a conflicted state?